# MVC ELMAH v/s Application_Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, exception, elmah, error-logging, application-error

**Background**

I had [[HandleError]](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/07/14/asp-net-mvc-preview-4-release-part-1.aspx) in place in my MVC web app for exception handling but later it couldn't handle some exceptions so I was suggested to move on to the alternative [**Application_Error**](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/5/exception_handling_in_asp_net_mvc) ([my SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183653)) I also ended up using [**ELMAH**](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) which seems better.

Well, ELMAH rocks! But I was unable to find how to show formatted exception with it (like I do with Application_Error)

### **ELMAH v/s Application_Error**

**ELMAH** - Provides (almost) out of the box exception logging and other features like email. Its completely dependent on web.config and a bunch of files it requires. Able to log exception in xml / database (as configured) and is capable of email, rss, etc. Provides a page where user can view the full exception log and drilldown for details.

> **Pros:** Doesn't show formatted exception upon error. Makes the web.config a bit bulky. The set of ELMAH files is 2.8mb (more then
>   twice the size of my entire web app zip). Can't format error / email. It is dependent
>   on System.Data.SQLite.dll which is CPU architectue dependent (x64 or
>   x86) [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929)

**Application_Error** - Catches all the exception and we're able to navigate user to show a formatted error. We control what is being showed and Emailed. Completely managed code (no CPU dependency) no extra web.config settings. No extra dlls.

> **Pros:** No implicit exception logging (we need to code). No log viewer
>   like ELMAH. Email, logging - we've to manage all.

CONCLUSION:
Firstly, please tell me if ELMAH can "completely" replace my Application_Error. Also, I didn't find much on how to configure the error message being displayed / emailed with ELMAH. Or do they have to **co-exist** *(Application_Error to show formatted error and ELMAH for pretty much everything else)*

Please suggest and share your experience.

Comment: better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can live with ELMAH (except for showing formatted exception details to the user - or atleast I didn't find anything for that)

I wonder what was missing in my post to attract SO audience. I got my thread answered by Atif himself - quicker, simpler!

> https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/elmah/Md9DslGgwNo