# Handling UnauthorizedAccessException with custom errors in MVC 4 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, custom-error-pages, custom-error-handling

I have enabled the global error handling for an application by applying the HandleError attribute within the filterConfig registration.

```
 public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

I am then using the custom errors (web.config) to hopefully display a friendly error message for each server error.

```
 <customErrors mode="On"  ></customErrors>
```

This seemed to be working fine for most exceptions and I was getting the expected behaviour in that the custom error page View (Error.cshtml in the shared view folder) was being displayed.

However I have recently noticed that this is not the behaviour I see if the error thrown is an UnauthorizedAccessException.

I am a bit stumped with this, as looking in fiddler I see that this UnauthorizedAccessException exception returns a plain 500 internal server error as a standard exception does.

So how come the standard exception abides by my customError setup but the UnauthorizedAccessException  does not?

ANd how can I get them to behave the same, as they are both essentially an error which I want to prevent the end user from seeing.

Comment: look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183653/mvc-handleerror-filter-didnt-catch-an-exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post provided me with the overview of exception handling to enable me to decide how to handle the unauthorizedAccessException, which essentially means handling them within the Application_OnStart.

http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/5/exception_handling_in_asp_net_mvc

For my purposes there doesn't seem much point in handling the errors with the HandleErrorAttribute and in the global Application_OnStart so for my purposes I decided it was best to handle everything in the Application_OnSTart,

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to force 'unhandled' exceptions like `UnauthorizedAccessException` to go through the normal custom-error page then you can override the controller's OnException method similar to the following:

```
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnException(filterContext);

        if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled && filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
        {
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            filterContext.Result = View("Error",
                new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, filterContext.GetCurrentControllerName(), filterContext.GetCurrentActionName()));
        }
    }
```

The article that you referenced is an excellent resource for a more thorough explanation of error-handling techniques, though, and should be considered as well.